# Trying to locate a menu file that is not into the Menus Manager

Tags: menu

I am trying to locate a Menu that is not located in the Menu Manager.
The website is: http://wholechild.it

The menu I am trying to locate is the ABOUT US. It doesn't seem to be created same as the other menus. The class is different and it has an inline CSS style I would like to edit as well. I want to find the file that controls this ABOUT US, to translate it into Italian. I don't know if it's controlled by a module or by a component.

Thanks in advance to everyone that could help me find this file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought, if you are only looking to change the words 'About Us' have you looked at creating a language override? Extensions > Languages > Overrides > New. Then in the bottom right make sure 'Value' is selected and type in 'About Us' to search for the language constant. You can then change it to what ever you want.

Answer (score 1):

That class seems to relate the the Helix Megamenu, rather than being core Joomla.

CMS-on-top-of-a-CMS extensions like Helix are usually an awful mess, but I'd try reading the Megamenu [documentation](https://www.joomshaper.com/documentation/helix-framework/helix3#megamenu) and look in the places it mentions.

Comment: Hey, I looked through there, it doesn't seem to be assigned from Helix Mega Menu. I think that it's a custom-made link because I see that it's has that inline CSS attached to it...

Comment: This may be relevant http://documentation.flytheme.net/sp-mega-menu/